# Is a familiar compelled when their wizard is?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars

I have a party and an aboleth dominated them (only two players present). The aboleth didn't do anything to the wizard's familiar. Does the wizard's familiar get affected by the compulsion effect too?
Would a familiar always know if their wizard was affected by a compulsion? (In my case the aboleth was out of view and hearing when casting)

In play I ruled that the familiar could act freely, as it had a reasonable intelligence score (Int 8 for wiz level 5). It tried to save its wizard but failed. Eventually the aboleth told the wizard to reign in their familiar. Now the party has a new subterranean "quest giver."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. in the dominate person spell (which functions the same as dominate monster but with the humanoid target restriction) not only does it target one creature but is based around giving personal commands, *and* in the familiars rules the highest telepathic link ability is the empathic link which only conveys general emotions (note: the speak with master ability is a turn on and off ability not a constant mind link and is only based around speech) so in summary the spell like ability is a single target ability and the familiar is not linked past emotions which aren’t even mentioned in the spell so the rules say no the familiar would not be affected